# How convert java type to domain of postgres with hibernate(springData)?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, nhibernate-mapping

i created domain in postgres:

```
create domain arrayofids as numeric[];
```

Now i want to use the domain in spring data like this:

```
String fakeQuery = "unnest(CAST (:ids AS arrayofids))";
Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(fakeQuery);
BigInteger[] arrayOfids = new BigInteger[] {new BigInteger("1"),new BigInteger("2)} //or It can be List. It is not important
nativeQuery.setParameter("ids", arrayOfids);
List resultList = nativeQuery.getResultList();
```

Of course i get Error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to arrayofIds
```

Before i used https://dalesbred.org/docs/api/org/dalesbred/datatype/SqlArray.html and it worked fine or did custom types in JDBC myself. Hibernate doesn't allow use my domain easy.

Query like that:

```
select * from mtTbale where id in :ids
```

is not interested. I should use the domain with unnest and  CAST

Answer (score 0):

Make :ids as a text representation of an array of numbers, i.e. "{1, 2}" and add SELECT to the query.
Try this:

```
String fakeQuery = "SELECT unnest(CAST (:ids AS arrayofids))";
Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(fakeQuery);
String arrayOfids = "{" + 1 + ", " + 2 + "}"; // obtain the string as is relevant in your case
nativeQuery.setParameter("ids", arrayOfids);
List resultList = nativeQuery.getResultList();
```

and the second query should look like this:

```
select * from mtTbale where id = ANY(CAST(:ids AS arrayofids));
```

You may also use Postgres shorthand (and more readable) cast syntax.
Instead of `CAST(:ids AS arrayofids)` use `:ids::arrayofids`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. About Postgres shorthand i didn't know. Thanks.

Comment: About string. It seems to me, that cast parameters(java objects) to string and use the string in parameter of query is not good idea for production. if there is not better way to reach my goal, may be i will use your advice)

Comment: Well, Java objects and Postgres domains are very different animals. Using intermediate text representation is very flexible and not a bad idea at all.

Comment: I agree with you, they are different. But what about array? I think array of BigInteger and array of numeric should not be very different, but  i didn't succeed to find easy way cast bigInteger[] to numeric[]

Comment: The problem is that in fact your database abstraction layer is not transferring BigInteger[] to Postgres but bytea (obviously the binary native representation of BigInteger[]). Postgres readily casts bigint[] to numeric[]. Look at ths: `select ('{1,2,3}'::bigint[])::numeric[];`